# Swift JSON objects decoding error. How to write it correctly?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, decode

I have a data decoding error. How to write it correctly?

typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

My JSON object:

```
struct LeagueDocument: Codable {
    var id: LeagueId
    var name: LeagueName
    var area: Area
    var startDate: String
    var endDate: String
    
    init(id: LeagueId, name: LeagueName, area: Area, startDate: String, endDate: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.area = area
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = endDate
    }
}

enum Area: String, Codable {
    case POLAND, ENGLAND, FRANCE, SPAIN, GERMANY, ITALY, EUROPE, UEFA_CHAMPIONS_LEAGUE, EUROPE_LEAGUE
}
```

JSON which I got from server:

```
[
  {
    "id": "ba4ddfd6-cb91-4ea7-853d-79be89917445",
    "name": "Liga 1 ",
    "area": "POLAND",
    "startDate": "2021-02-28",
    "endDate": "2022-02-28"
  },
  {
    "id": "4061b62b-dd57-4916-adf4-e0874ec767b1",
    "name": "Liga 2",
    "area": "POLAND",
    "startDate": "2021-02-01",
    "endDate": "2021-05-11"
  }
]
```

My code:

```
func getAllActiveLeagues(completion: @escaping ([LeagueDocument]) -> Void) {
```

(...)

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
    if data != nil {
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode([LeagueDocument].self, from: data!)
            completion(decodedData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } else {
        print("Data is nil")
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: It should be fine. Could you replace `print(error)` with `print("Error: \(error) with responseString: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)")`, and tell us what's the output?

Comment: The JSON represents an array, it doesn't cause the error. And - unrelated – *"Data is nil"* is never going to be displayed, if `error` is `nil` then `data` is guaranteed to have a value, you can force unwrap it. And what is `LeagueId` and `LeagueName`?

Comment: I ask you to print the data (with String conversion UTF8 encoding) because you are assuming that the response is the JSON you've shown, and it shouldn't create an error (tested it adding `typealias LeagueId = String` and for `LeagueName`),  but in reality you have another JSON. An error JSON? A dictionary encapsulating your expected JSON? We can't guess.

Comment: I found a bug. When I was converting json to string I saw it was a server error with authorization. Thanks for the advice.